# Iterate through the same data name

Tags: .net, vb.net, foreach

[image]
How can I iterate the data only from first floor?

```
For Each dtrow in CameraDtable.Rows
    'get datas only from 1F
Next
```

Comment: "SELECT *  FROM tableName WHERE Floor = '1F'" or `thisFloor() As DataRow =CameraDtable.Select("Floor = 1F")`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: how do I put that on a `For Each`?

Comment: if you create the DT so it a) only has the floor you want in the first place OR b) Filter to the rows for 1F, then you do it OUTSIDE a for loop, then just iterate each row - they will ALL be 1F. OR keep it the way you have it and add an if: something like `If dtRow.Floor = "1F" Then...`

Comment: Option3 is working, how about Option2? I can't code it. I think its better, why don't you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each dtrow In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.Select("Floor ='1'")
    ' do code
Next
```

OR

```
For Each dtrow In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.Rows
If dtrow("Floor") = 1 Then
    ' do code
End If
Next
```